# Multiple Nodes per Line in Neo4j Batch Import Tool

Tags: neo4j

Using [Neo4j's Batch Import Tool](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool-basic-example.html), how can I create multiple nodes from a single row, and then attribute some properties to Node 1 and some to Node 2?

This is an example from [29.3](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool-basic-example.html):
movieId:ID,title,year:int,:LABEL
tt0133093,"The Matrix",1999,Movie
tt0234215,"The Matrix Reloaded",2003,Movie;Sequel
tt0242653,"The Matrix Revolutions",2003,Movie;Sequel

Is there a way to make it so title is "movieId.title" and year is its own ID? Then I can abstract that out to multiple nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-use the same csv file but use two different header files, with different columns used as `:ID` and columns you don't want for this node as `:IGNORED`

As the header is independent from the data you can use that approach to pull in the same file several times for different nodes, relationships, etc.

It's also explained here: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_super_fast_batch_importer_for_huge_datasets

Answer (score 3):

The import tool (in contrast to `LOAD CSV`) expects exactly one node per line. So you have to use some preprocessing to make the format fitting your desired graph model.

Typical candidates for this a [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org) or the usual suspects from a unix command line: sed, awk, ...

In your case I'd strip out the title into a separate file for creating the `:Title` nodes, and create another csv file for the relationships between movies and titles.